# Watch for changes in RDF graph using Fuseki

Tags: rdf, sparql, owl, fuseki, apache-jena

How to watch for changes to an RDF model? i.e. to have some function called when the graph is updated.

Is it possible with Fuseki?

I need Fuseki for answering SPARQL queries over HTTP.
I don't want to reinvent the wheel (i.e. do this in Apache Jena, instead of using Fuseki) just to have this feature.

I also accept other solutions where the SPARQL server is already there and allows to be notified of changes.
I checked for Stardog and this does not seem to be possible.

Comment: What is "some function" and where does it need to be called? i.e. on the server, on some other server, on some connected client(s) or somewhere else

Comment: Either. In the simplest case I want to call it on the server, even in the same JVM of the server. It would be really nice if a client can register itself for watching for changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get notification of changes on top of SPARQL endpoint:

- RSS like feeds for change notification, check [sparqlPuSH: Proactive notification of data updates in RDF stores using PubSubHubbub](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-699/Paper6.pdf) .
- The other alternative could be an extension of Pingback method of blogosphere, check [Weaving a  Social Data Web with Semantic Pingback](http://aksw.org/Projects/SemanticPingback.html) (this probably is far from what u wanted)